# I can not enable wallet, how can I enable it? already deleted disablewallet=1 from conf

Tags: bitcoind

how can I enable wallet in my node. 
I put disablewallet=1

but now I want to enable wallet, I deleted that line... but I get no wallet...
how can I get a wallet_

Comment: Did you restart the node after changing the config file?

Comment: yes, I had to start all over again... just restarting the node was not taking changes after deleting disablewallet=1

Comment: Double check that the command that you used to restart bitcoind with also doesn't have `-disablewallet=1` or `-nowallet` or `-wallet=0`